# Regex: how to stop match on certain words that cannot exists

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The title is so confusing, I admit it - if you want to change it you are welcome.

I'm working on PHP and preg_match function.

The problem is this string (just an example)

```
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

`ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` (another example..)

i need to find ON DELETE and ON UPDATE values, but they can't be there both.

So sometimes i have this:

```
ON DELETE something
```

and other times:

```
ON UPDATE something
```

and other times both.

So, this regex doesn't cover all possibilities:

```
/ON DELETE (.+) ON UPDATE (.+)/
```

If i put

`/ON DELETE (.+)( ON UPDATE (.*))?/` -- to cover the case in which there isn't ON UPDATE

if ON UPDATE is present, first group results in "SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE".

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookaround if you want to avoid matching too much:

Negative lookahead :

```
/ON DELETE ((?:(?! ON UPDATE).)+)( ON UPDATE (.*))?/
```

To capture disregarding the order:

```
/(?:ON DELETE ((?:(?! ON UPDATE).)+)|ON UPDATE ((?:(?! ON DELETE).)+))/
```

But what exactly do you want? Remove both if they exist?

Comment: ok, i updated my answer. if you want to match if both exist and also if only one of them exists, the second regex should do it.

Answer (score 0):

use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to check your regexp

Answer (score 0):

psuedo code to match occurance of on delete and on update but not both

```
function valid(str)
{
 matchDelete=regex(str, 'ON DELETE'); //true for match
 matchUpdate=regex(str, 'ON UPDATE'); //true for match

 if(   (matchDelete || matchUpdate ) && !(matchDelete && matchUpdate)  )
 {
   valid match
 }
}
```